# How to make a very DENSE mocha?

Tags: flavored-coffee, mocha

I know have to add milk and chocolate into the coffee, but it tastes different from bought from shop.

I am using whole milk, not steamed, circa 1/5th of the total volume.
My coffee is Caffe Verona dark roast.

Comment: What type of milk are you using at home? 1%? 2%? AKA skimmed, semi-skimmed... What sort of cocoa powder are you using?

Comment: Yes, the whole milk is about 1/5 of the total volume. And the cocoa powder is called Caffe Verona dark roast ground coffee. Excuse me, what do you mean by skimmed?

Comment: Are you steam frothing your milk? And if you are, have you checked the milk by itself to check thickness?

Comment: No, I add the milk after brew. And, it is normal whole milk. Do you mean the thickness of mocha is determined by milk?

Comment: Mochas are latte-based drinks. They use steamed and frothed milk, not just plain milk. Steamed and frothed milk are both produced by mixing air and heat with milk (typically by injecting steam, by heating and agitating, or by a combination of these) to make it creamier. You can make frothed milk without special tools by agitating milk aggressively while heating it on the stove. Use a hand mixer or immersion blender. If you like the effect, you can buy dedicated frother devices for about $30-40 online.

Comment: This is very informative and helpful. Let me try to make steamed and frothed milk. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the mentioned “Caffe Verona dark roast ground coffee” is _not_ the name of the cocoa?

Comment: @RMac reads like an answer to me? I think both the site and you (hello upvotes!) would benefit if you could turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Stephie Posted it.

Comment: Can you please update your question do include how you brew your coffee and how exactly you make your beverage?

Answer (score 2):

Posting comment on original question as an answer to benefit the Google creepy crawly bot.

Mochas are latte-based drinks. They use steamed and frothed milk, not just plain milk. Steamed and frothed milk are both produced by mixing air and heat with milk (typically by injecting steam, by heating and agitating, or by a combination of these) to make it creamier. You can make frothed milk without special tools by agitating milk aggressively while heating it on the stove. Use a hand mixer or immersion blender. If you like the effect, you can buy dedicated frother devices for about $30-40 online.

Answer (score 1):

The mouthfeel of a mocha is based on the milk. More precisely, the creaminess that comes from the tiny bubbles in the steamed and frothed milk. You get the “fullest” or “densest” effect when you create a microfoam instead of large bubbles and a stiff foam.

Apart from that, the ratio of milk in a mocha is significantly higher than the 20% you are using right now - and without enough milk, you end up with a watery drink, unless you are using specific thickeners.

In short, add espresso and chocolate/cocoa to frothed milk, not a bit of milk to a large amount of coffee. That said, there’s of course nothing wrong per se with your ratios, especially if you like the flavor, just the dense texture will be impossible to achieve without using a suitable thickener.